# Update one column with two conditions

Tags: postgresql

I want to do the following:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET column1 = 10 * t2.column1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.column2 = 'yyy'

UPDATE table1 t1
SET column1 = 10 * t2.column2
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.column2 = 'zzz'
```

Is it possible to keep it in one semantic block?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE WHEN ..` and apply the update only at the rows with valid condition  ( 'yyy'  OR 'zzz' )

```
    UPDATE table1 t1 
    SET    column1 = CASE 
            WHEN t1.column2 = 'yyy' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column1 
            WHEN t1.column2 = 'zzz' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column2 
    end
    FROM   table2 t2
    WHERE t1.column2  IN ( 'yyy','zzz')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET    column1 = ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN t1.column2 = 'yyy' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column1 
              WHEN t1.column2 = 'zzz' THEN column1 = 10 * t2.column2 
       end) 
FROM   table2 t2
```

Comment: Your query will assign `null` to every `column1` where `column2` not 'yyy' neither 'zzz' so be carefully. Your query cross joins table1 and table2. However the question doing this also.

Comment: i get this error: column1 is of type numeric, but the expression is of type boolean Line3: CASE